# How to escape backslashes in R string

Tags: r, file-io, escaping, backslash

I'm writing strings which contain backslashes (`\`) to a file:

```
x1 = "\\str"

x2 = "\\\str"
# Error: '\s' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting "\\\s"

x2="\\\\str"
write(file = 'test', c(x1, x2))
```

When I open the file named `test`, I see this:

```
\str
\\str
```

If I want to get  a string containing 5 backslashes, should I write 10 backslashes, like this?

```
x = "\\\\\\\\\\str"
```

Comment: From `R 4.0.0` raw strings are supported. See [Escaping backslash (\) in string or paths in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14185287/escaping-backslash-in-string-or-paths-in-r/63078969#63078969)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> [...] ***If I want to get a string containing 5 `\` ,should i write 10 `\`*** [...]

Yes, you should. To write a single `\` in a string, you write it as `"\\"`.

This is because the `\` is a special character, reserved to *escape* the character that follows it. (Perhaps you recognize `\n` as newline.) It's also useful if you want to write a string containing a single `"`. You write it as `"\""`.

The reason why `\\\str` is invalid, is because it's interpreted as `\\` (which corresponds to a single `\`) followed by `\s`, which is not valid, since "escaped `s`" has no meaning.

Comment: No equivalent of Python's ["raw strings"](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2081708/1175496) , as in: `r'allows\unescaped\backslashes'` ?

Comment: @TheRedPea Yes, from `R 4.0.0` raw strings are supported. See e.g. [Escaping backslash (\) in string or paths in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14185287/escaping-backslash-in-string-or-paths-in-r/63078969#63078969)

Answer (score 8):

Have a read of [this section](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.html#Character-vectors) about character vectors.

In essence, it says that when you enter character string literals you enclose them in a pair of quotes (" or '). Inside those quotes, you can create special characters using \ as an escape character.

For example, \n denotes new line or \" can be used to enter a " without R thinking it's the end of the string. Since \ is an escape character, you need a way to enter an actual . This is done by using \\. Escaping the escape!

Answer (score 6):

Note that the doubling of backslashes is because you are entering the string at the command line and the string is first parsed by the R parser.  You can enter strings in different ways, some of which don't need the doubling.  For example:

```
> tmp <- scan(what='')
1: \\\\\str
2: 
Read 1 item
> print(tmp)
[1] "\\\\\\\\\\str"
> cat(tmp, '\n')
\\\\\str 
>
```

Comment: This no longer happens in R 4.x