# Escaping backslash (\) in string or paths in R

Tags: r, file-io, directory, path, escaping

Windows copies path with backslash `\`, which R does not accept. So, I wanted to write a function which would convert `\` to `/`. For example:

```
chartr0 <- function(foo) chartr('\','\\/',foo)
```

Then use `chartr0` as...

```
source(chartr0('E:\RStuff\test.r'))
```

But `chartr0` is not working. I guess, I am unable to escape `/`. I guess escaping `/` may be important in many other occasions.

Also, is it possible to avoid the use `chartr0` every time, but convert all path automatically by creating an environment in R which calls `chartr0` or use some kind of temporary use like using `options`

Comment: Or just use forward slashes...

Comment: As Dirk says, with the reason being that forward-slashes do not need to be "escaped".

Comment: You can use file.path("E:","Rstuf","test.r").

Comment: There is an interesting solution to the windows slash problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12703931/1700987

Answer (score 30, accepted):

From [R 4.0.0](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/NEWS.html) you can use `r"(...)"` to write a path as [raw string constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_literal#Raw_strings), which avoids the need for escaping:

```
r"(E:\RStuff\test.r)"
# [1] "E:\\RStuff\\test.r"
```

> There is a new syntax for specifying raw character constants similar to the one used in C++: `r"(...)"` with `...` any character sequence not containing the sequence `)"`. This makes it *easier to write strings that contain backslashes* or both single and double quotes. For more details see `?Quotes`.

Answer (score 7):

Your fundamental problem is that R will signal an error condition as soon as it sees a single back-slash before any character other than a few lower-case letters, backslashes themselves, quotes or some conventions for entering octal, hex or Unicode sequences. That is because the interpreter sees the back-slash as a message to "escape" the usual translation of characters and do something else. If you want a single back-slash in your character element you need to type 2 backslashes. That will create one backslash:

```
nchar("\\")
#[1] 1
```

The "Character vectors" section of _Intro_to_R_ says:

"Character strings are entered using either matching double (") or single (') quotes, but are printed using double quotes (or sometimes without quotes). They use C-style escape sequences, using \ as the escape character, so \ is entered and printed as \, and inside double quotes " is entered as \". Other useful escape sequences are \n, newline, \t, tab and \b, backspace—see ?Quotes for a full list."

```
 ?Quotes
```

Answer (score 3):

```
chartr0 <- function(foo) chartr('\\','/',foo)
chartr0('E:\\RStuff\\test.r')
```

You cannot write E:\Rxxxx, because R believes R is escaped.

Comment: This would work just as well: `chartr0 <- function(foo) chartr('\\','/',foo)`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that every single forward slash and backslash in your code is escaped incorrectly, resulting in either an invalid string or the wrong string being used. You need to read up on which characters need to be escaped and how. Take a look at the list of escape sequences in the link below. Anything not listed there (such as the forward slash) is treated literally and does not require any escaping.

http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-lang.html#Literal-constants

Comment: It is true that the backslashes were not entered correctly but I do not understand the statement that the forward-slashes were escaped incorrectly.

Comment: in `chartr('\','\\/',foo)`, it appears that the `'\\/'` was an attempt to escape the forward slash with an escaped backslash. Perhaps that is an incorrect assumption, but in any case `'\\/'` is clearly a wrong input for `chartr`.

Comment: It was not the '\\/' that caused the error but rather the `'\','` sequence.