# Error: '\P' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting ""C:\P"

Tags: r, installation

I freshly installed R 3.1.3 on Windows 7. I have two issues when starting RGui:

- R Console showing me
  Error: '\P' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting ""C:\P"
- File "Rprofile.site" gets ignored.

```
No changes made in the file "Rcmd_environ":
R_SHARE_DIR=${R_HOME}/share
R_INCLUDE_DIR=${R_HOME}/include
R_DOC_DIR=${R_HOME}/doc
```

Program runs under C:\Program Files\R\R-3.1.3\
Any hints or thoughts how to solve this?

Comment: Use `/` instead of Windows \ for directories

Comment: Probably also helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/q/17605563

Answer (score 2):

The `\`-character is used for escape sequences (control characters like line breaks (`\n`, sometimes `\r\n`), tabs (`\t`) and others).

If you want a literal `\` in a string, you have to escape it with another `\`, so just write `"C:\\P..."`