# How to enter a character string verbatim in R?

Tags: r

Similar to [How to write string literals in python without having to escape them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4703516/how-to-write-string-literals-in-python-without-having-to-escape-them), I wish to have a character string storing a path to a directory copied from the windows explorer. E.g.

```
dir <- 'C:\Users'
```

I don't want to have to escape the backwards slash.

Comment: Relevant - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17605563/efficiently-convert-backslash-to-forward-slash-in-r#comment25625528_17605617

Comment: excellent, thanks, so it looks like `readline` or `readClipboard` is the way to go.