# Where is my output text file from an R-script run in unix?

Tags: r, unix, text-files, rscript

I am using R on a Unix system. I wrote an R script in windows, and uploaded it to Unix (via putty), such that I could run the script in R (in unix) with the command `source('CODE.R')`.

Now, here is the problem. In my R script, I wrote `write.table(myDataOutput, file = "/myfolder/wantedData.txt")` as my output, but after running the script, the text file is nowhere to be found (not in any folder).

I did some research on google, but it seemed that my question is kind of too specific, and I did not manage to find a similar problem.

Please help me. Thank you!

ps: now the slash is updated. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have had this problem myself, not being able to figure out the default directory which R uses for a file with a relative path.  Since you used an absolute path, the file should be found at `\myfolder\wantedData.txt`.  If it isn't there, you can try searching for it:

```
sudo find . -name 'wantedData.txt`
```

If this search comes up empty, then R did not write the file.  If you find it, but in a location which you did not expect, then most likely R interpreted your path as a *relative*, rather than absolute, path.  In this case, remember the location so you can find your file next time.

**Update**

Based on the warning message you got from Unix, I would guess that your R script does not have permissions to write the output file in the location you specified.  You could try running the R script with `sudo`, which might get around this problem.

Comment: I don't think the file can be written to a non-existent directory. If this is a relative path (and I think it is) I'm not sure `myfolder` exists. (And of course, a backslash doesn't even work on windows without escaping it and it certainly doesn't work on a *nix system.)

Comment: @Roland He mentioned that the script was run on Unix.  `\myfolder` does _not_ mean something relative in the UNIX file system, it means a folder called `myfolder` located directly under the root.  Hence, it is a mystery why R would interpret a directory path in this way.

Comment: I actually get a warning from the system. How so?

Comment: What is the "warning?"  If you can't find the file anywhere, it probably never got written.

Comment: I did not recall the whole message, but it did mention "the incident will be reported". Anyway, I have run the script (with simple dataset) in windows, and it is fine with the output files produced properly...

Comment: Hi, I realize the plausible problem of the warning. I am running unix on the server, and sudo is usually for administrator, so that is where the warning comes in. Regarding the permission, I did a test with a very simple data set (the built-in dataset, "cars"), and `write.table(cars, file="junk.txt")`, and it worked...

Answer (score 0):

Welcome on SO. [This SuperUser question](https://superuser.com/questions/176388/why-does-windows-use-backslashes-for-paths-and-unix-forward-slashes) explains why Windows uses backslashes and Unix forward slashes in file paths. [This SNAP TECH](https://blog.snap.uaf.edu/2012/05/24/quick-way-to-make-r-scripts-run-on-multiple-operating-systems/) blog post introduces a `choose.OS` function that is useful if you work with different OS. [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17605563/efficiently-convert-backslash-to-forward-slash-in-r) explains how to efficiently convert backslash to forward slash.