# Using single slash while reading file path

Tags: r

How do I ensure I read my files using the exact file path as provided by Windows?
For instance, this works:

```
myimg<-image_read("C:\\Users\\Nelson\\Desktop\\hypo.jpg")
```

But Not this:

```
myimg<-image_read("C:\Users\Nelson\Desktop\hypo.jpg")
```

What is the reason behind this?

Comment: *why* questions are very broad (IMO), but I think that [seancarmody's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11806550/1286528) in linked post answers it.

Comment: @NelsonGon From R 4.0.0 raw strings are supported. See [Escaping backslash () in string or paths in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14185287/escaping-backslash-in-string-or-paths-in-r/63078969#63078969)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In R, a single backslash is an escape character, and using it for directory paths will always produce an error: https://kb.iu.edu/d/azzp

For conversion see:
[Efficiently convert backslash to forward slash in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17605563/efficiently-convert-backslash-to-forward-slash-in-r)

Comment: Or use double backslash. This may be convenient for (some) Windows users.