# R: how to get rid of the \ character in R

Tags: r, separator, slash

I am importing a table with the following code:

```
data <- read.csv("E:/test_division/division_finale2009/file_list_months_weeks/scope_ais_april.csv", nrows=1000, sep=",")
t<-subset(data,data$mmsi==211330370)
```

When I have a look to my data, it seems that there is a mistake in the column `dimBow`:
[image]

The sign `"\"` here is prohibiting the separator `","` to take effect.

I have tried to remove the `"\"` from the column `dimBow`, but without sucess with

```
   t$dimBow<-gsub("\", "", t$dimBow)
```

I don't see why this command is not doing anything. I can remove all the other special characters, but not `"\"`

This file was generated by me, so if I find a way to remove all of the `"\"` in this sample, I could create in the future other files without the `"\"`.

Comment: or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25424382/how-to-replace-single-backslash-in-r

Answer (score 0):

"\" need to be escaped,try this

```
t$dimBow<-gsub("\\\\", "", t$dimBow)
```

or

```
t$dimBow<-gsub("[\\]", "", t$dimBow)
```

more can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11806501/backslash-in-r-string)