# Removing "\037" from strings in R

Tags: r, cjk

I am preparing a dataset that contains `CJK` characters with R and mostly through Tidyverse. During the process, I found that some character elements has `\037` at the very end.

```
# A tibble: 99 × 2
     Prefecture     n
            <chr> <int>
1            \037     1
2      北海道\037     1
3          北海道    13
4          北海道     4
...          ...     ...
```

I have tried to remove them with the line below:

```
library(stringr)
out.file %>% mutate(
    Prefecture = str_replace_all(out.file$Prefecture, "\\\\037", "")
)
```

The `str_replace_all` does remove all the `\037`s when being tested on a string. When applying `mutate` on an entire column, however, the lines above still gives the same results in the first code chunk in this post.

What would be the most efficient way to remove them from strings?

**Update with solution**

```
require(stringi)
out.file %>% 
mutate(Prefecture = stri_escape_unicode(Prefecture), 
       Prefecture = str_replace_all(Prefecture, "\037", ""),
       Prefecture = stri_unescape_unicode(Prefecture))
```

This way I am able to resolve the issue successfully.

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25466734/1000343

Comment: Thanks! @TylerRinker. That was a helpful post, I was able to escape from `CJK`,  replace the unwanted characters, and unescape them all. This solves my issue.