# How to write a function to change "\" to "/" in R

Tags: r, rstudio

Firstly, I understand that "\" is an R escape character and also the file path separator on windows.

I know that it can be escaped by using either / or \.

I am developing a package and I want a function for the user to literally just be able to call it like:

```
makeFileLocationRCompatable("H:\Temp")
```

and for the function to return

```
"H:/Temp"
```

or

```
"H:\\Temp"
```

but it seems to be impossible in R due to the fact that \ escapes the following character.

I don't want my users to have to change the way they input the file path.

Any ideas?

Comment: this might be helpful (see the comment below the accepted answer): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25424382/how-to-replace-single-backslash-in-r.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to replace single backslash in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25424382/how-to-replace-single-backslash-in-r)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Rstudio snippetsaddin to convert the slash 
download it from here.

```
devtools::install_github("sfr/RStudio-Addin-Snippets", type = "source")

Restart Rstudio.
Select the path or the code where slashes needs to be replaced. 
Click on Addin -> select convert slash
It will reverse all slashes if the path is selected.
```

Answer (score 1):

`normalizePath` from the `base` package might provide this functionality? (I cannot test on Windows myself; sorry if this is a moot proposal)

For example

```
normalizePath('H:\\Temp', winslash = '\\')
```

See also `?normalizePath`