# For loop of gsub with variable pattern plus regex end of line R

Tags: r, gsub

My question is how to do what the answer of [this question][1] does, but only matching when the pattern ends with the end of the string.

my idea was adding $ after the pattern, to indicate the end of the line, exemple:

```
removePunctuation <- function(punctuationObject){
  itemsToBeRemoved <- c(".", ",", ";", ":", "'", "!", "#", "-", "--")
  resultObject <- punctuationObject
  for (itemToReplace in itemsToBeRemoved){
    resultObject <- gsub(itemToReplace$, "", resultObject, fixed = TRUE)
  }
  resultObject
}
```

but it doesnt work. i tried many variations of the same thing, but i cant get the $ to be read as regex after stating a variable pattern such as the 'itemToReplace'.
[1]: [For loop over list of items to use in R's gsub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56959209/for-loop-over-list-of-items-to-use-in-rs-gsub)

Comment: You have to `paste0` the dollar symbol onto the `itemToReplace` object. But you will have difficulty because you have `fixed=TRUE`. ;|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you can use `sub` instead of `gsub`. Second, you need to paste the `$` onto the end of the itemsToBeRemoved. But since `$` is a metacharacter, you cannot use `fixed=TRUE` in your `gsub` call. One solution to that problem is to enclose the punctuation items within `[]`:

```
removePunctuation <- function(punctuationObject){
  itemsToBeRemoved <- c(".", ",", ";", ":", "'", "!", "#", "-", "--")
  resultObject <- punctuationObject
  for (itemToReplace in itemsToBeRemoved){
    resultObject <- sub(paste0("[", itemToReplace, ']$'), "", resultObject)
  }
  resultObject
}
```

Test:

```
removePunctuation("Hello, I use R.")
# [1] "Hello, I use R"
```

Comment: i have an object with multiple strings, so i do need to use gsub, should i update the question?

Comment: I don't think so because, in your loop, you are selecting only one item from the multi-item string object. The other poster agrees.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `sub` for that task to *remove variables at the end of the line*.

```
s <- c("x", ".x", "x.", "x--x", "x--", "x---")

sub("(--|[.,;:'!#-])$", "", s)
#[1] "x"    ".x"   "x"    "x--x" "x"    "x-"
```