# gsub and backslashes in R

Tags: r, gsub

I have the following string:

> c(\"Yes \", \" No\")

I want to remove the backslashes such that it becomes:

> c("Yes", "No)

I tried the following, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25424382/replace-single-backslash-in-r):

```
gsub("\\","", "c(\"Yes \", \" No\")", fixed = TRUE)
```

But it does not work, so I must have misunderstood something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a double quote, so either remove the quote and replace with blank

```
gsub('"',"", "c(\"Yes \", \" No\")", fixed = TRUE)
#[1] "c(Yes ,  No)"
```

or replace with a single quote

```
gsub('"',"'", "c(\"Yes \", \" No\")", fixed = TRUE)
#[1] "c('Yes ', ' No')"
```

---

If we print with `cat`, the character `\` doesn't exist

```
cat("c(\"Yes \", \" No\")")
#c("Yes ", " No")


nchar('\"')
#[1] 1

cat('\"')
#"
```

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean, "it is a double quote"?

Comment: I want the quotes there, but not the backslashes.

Answer (score 0):

The quoted character string literal `"c(\"Yes \"…)"` does *not* contain backslashes. It contains [*escaped double quotes*](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Quotes.html). The escape char backslashes are displayed (only) when `print`ing the value in R (which happens automatically when executing the value in the R console). But they are not in the actual string, and saving, displaying or otherwise handling the string won’t see them.

For instance, you can show the true string value [via the `message` function](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/message.html):

```
message("c(\"Yes \", \" No\")")
```

Outputs:

```
c("Yes ", " No")
```

And, just to make it even clearer, `gsub` does not require special handling of backslashes in strings. *String literals* do, because backslash is the escape character.