# Remove backslashes from character string

Tags: r, r-faq

I am reading text in from a txt file and pass the contents to SQL. The SQL text contains double quotes and is causing problems. I would like to remove the "\" in the string below so I can send it to SQL

```
  test<- "select case when \"est\"  dsaf"
  test<-  cat(test, sep="")
  class(test)
```

returns an UNQUOTED null object

```
> test<- "select case when \"est\"  dsaf"
>   test<-  cat(test, sep="")
select case when "est"  dsaf
>   class(test)
[1] "NULL"
```

When I pass the unquoted string to SQL I get this error:

```
Error in odbcQuery(channel, query, rows_at_time) : 
  'getCharCE' must be called on a CHARSXP
```

and I would like it to return with the leading and trailing quotes then I can send it on to SQl and it will work.

```
[1] "select case when "est"  dsaf"
```

Comment: Believe it or not there is no backslash character in `"select case when \"est\"  dsaf"`. Please read `?Quotes`

Comment: @Richard - I cannot change them to single quotes they need to be double. Any idea how to eliminate the "\"

Comment: The `cat` only provides a side-effect and returns a NULL object.

Comment: what do you need to do in sql that you can't do in r?

Comment: Provide complete code that precedes the error. (If you are using the result from `cat`, then `test` is NULL.)

Comment: I credited your answer. It was correct. I did not need to use cat. See bottom of edit.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Perhaps you would like to see a different representation of the same string:

```
test2 <- 'select case when "est"  dsaf'
test<- "select case when \"est\"  dsaf"
identical(test, test2)
#[1] TRUE
```

When a character value is built with double quotes, any interior instances of `\"` become only double-quotes. They will be displayed by `print` (and by the REPL that you see in an interactive session) with the escape-backslash, but using `cat` you cant determine that they are not really in there as backslashes.

Further proof:

```
>  nchar("\"")
[1] 1
```

You can use either `cat` or print with `quote=FALSE` in you want to display the value as it really exists internally:

```
> print(test, quote=FALSE)
[1] select case when "est"  dsaf
```

This is evidence that at least one version of "SQL" agrees (or "accepts") that there is no backslash when `\"` appears in the interior of a string:

```
> require(sqldf)
Loading required package: sqldf
Loading required package: gsubfn
Loading required package: proto
Loading required package: RSQLite
Loading required package: DBI
> ?sqldf
> a1r <- head(warpbreaks)
> a1s <- sqldf("select * from warpbreaks limit 6")
Loading required package: tcltk
> a2s <- sqldf("select * from CO2 where Plant like 'Qn%'")
> 
> a2sdq <- sqldf("select * from CO2 where Plant like \"Qn%\"")
> identical(a2s,a2sdq)
[1] TRUE
```

So the was the first problem. The second problem was trying to assign the value of a `cat` call. The `cat` function always returns NULL after sending its value to a destination, possibly the console output. You cannot save the resulting character value to an R name. You always get NULL. See the `?cat` help page.

Comment: Do you have an answer?

Comment: I gave you an answer. There is no backslash to remove.

Comment: I am passing this to string to SQL and it does see the "\" that why i need to remove it.

Comment: Well saying that a computer or program "sees" something is not going to be accurate, now, is it? You need to provide code and an error message.

Comment: It sure is accurate. SQL "sees" the "\". I have used cat to remove the "\" but cat also remove the doubel quotes around the sql statement and after cat(test) the class of test is NULL

Comment: You are repeating anthropomorphic characterizations of programmatic behavior.  Please provide the requested code and error messages.

Comment: there is no error. See update. Cat removed the "\" but produces an unquoted object that I can't pass to SQL

Comment: Right. That's what `cat` is documented to return. You still have not provided any evidence that whatever instance of "SQL" is being communicated with is producing an error related tot he presence of a backslash in the test object.

Comment: See edit.       'getCharCE' must be called on a CHARSXP

Answer (score 0):

The solution in [R - gsub replacing backslashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27491986/r-gsub-replacing-backslashes) worked for me.

Example:

```
library(stringr)
df$variable <- str_replace(df$variable,"\\\\","")

df$variable before: "xyz\"
df$variable after:"xyz"
```