# Remove backslashes from string in R

Tags: r, string, gsub

#### [Link to R-Faq Duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28204507/903061) (different from above)

I have a string as follows:

```
 "[{\"Year\":\"\",\"Market\":\"The Place\",\"Due\":\"\"}]"
```

And I need to remove the backslashes to have:

```
"[{"Year":"","Market":"The Place","Due":""}]"
```

I have tried:

```
stri_unescape_unicode(theString)
```

and also:

```
gsub("\\","",theString)
```

But neither works.

Comment: How it prints is not what it is. Try writing `theString` to a file, or calling `cat(theString, "\n")`.

Comment: Interesting. So when I do cat(theString) is looks perfect. So this is actually what is there?

Comment: Didn't someone ask this yesterday? It might be worth working up a nice definitive explanation and giving it an [tag:r-faq] tag.

Comment: none of those approaches are working in this case.

Comment: The first line of that answer is very relevant: "There is no backslash in that string. The displayed backslash is an escape marker." This is demonstrated by Josh Ulrich's comment.

Comment: The danger in using `cat` to demonstrate the non-existence of the back-slash was demonstrated by the other questioner then trying to use the result of the `cat`-call and finding that it is NULL. (But getting a rather cryptic error message for his trouble.)  Better I advise would be to use `print(theString, quote=FALSE)`

Comment: @Gregor: Do you prefer the linked-to answer or the one I gave yesterday to a somewhat similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28204507/remove-backslashes-with-quotes/28204611#28204611 ? I think yesterday's answer was more complete.

Comment: @BondedDust Much prefer yours! I just added the [r-faq] tag and tried to make the title a little more general.