# How to replace "&" with "\&"

Tags: r, regex, gsub

I find it difficult to replace `"&"` with `"\&"` using R's `base` `gsub()` function -

```
gsub("&", "\&", "A&B")
```

Gives below error -

```
Error: '\&' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting ""\&"
```

Is there any way to achieve this substitution?

Comment: `gsub("&", "\\&", "A&B",fixed=TRUE)`

Comment: with this I am getting "A\\&B". I wanted to get "A\&B" (single escape)

Comment: No, you get `A\&B`, you only see double ``\`` in the console. Try `cat(...)`

Comment: One more answer about backslashes in R string literals  - [Escaping \ in string or paths in R](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14185627/3832970)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
gsub("&", "\\&", "A&B",fixed=TRUE) # Fixed string replacement
gsub("(&)", "\\\\\\1", "A&B")      # Regex replacement
```

The fixed string replacement is clear: every `&` is replaced with a `\&`. The double `\` is used in the string literal to denote a literal `\`.

In the regex replacement, the `&` is matched and captured into Group 1. Since a backslash is a special character in the regex replacement pattern, it must be doubled, and - keeping in mind a literal backslash is defined with `\\` inside a string literal - we need to use `\\\\` in the replacement. The `\1` is the backreference to Group 1 value, but again, the `\` must be doubled in the string, literal, hence, we use `\\1` in there. That is why there are 6 backslashes in a row. You may find more about backslashes problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28204611/3832970).

The result only contains a single backslash, you can easily check that using `cat` or saving the contents to a text file:

```
cat(gsub("&", "\\&", "A&B",fixed=TRUE), collapse="\n")
cat(gsub("(&)", "\\\\\\1", "A&B"))
```

See the [R demo online](https://tio.run/##K/r/PzmxRCO9uDRJQ0lNSUdBKSYGTDmqOSnppGVWpKbYhgSFumrqKCTn5@QkFhSn2irF5ClpciG0aahpQjSCgCFMs6bm//8A)

Comment: But if I pass this result to another variable that new variable still contains double escape. This is disgustedly confusing

Comment: @Bogaso See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28204611/3832970), that **DOES NOT** contain any double backslashes. ***Period***.

Comment: @Bogaso, function `cat` shows strings as they are, without doubling the backslashes. Try `cat(gsub("&", "\\&", "A&B",fixed=TRUE))`, it will show `A\&B`.