# Replace string with carriage return

Tags: r, regex

I´ve tried a lot of regex patterns and I´ve looked in other answers but have not managed to replace a dot with a carriage return in R. Here is a reprex:

```
col1 = c( "name.surname", "name.surname", "name.surname")
df <- as.data.frame( col1 )

# returns:
          col1
1 name.surname
2 name.surname
3 name.surname
```

I´ve tried many patterns like this:

```
gsub( "[.]", "[\\r]", df$col1 )

# returns:
[1] "name[r]surname" "name[r]surname" "name[r]surname"

# desired output:
    [1] "name     "name     "name
         surname"  surname"  surname"
```

I´d really appreciate if you could help me or point me to a similar question.

Best regards.

Comment: Tried `gsub(".", "\r", df$col1, fixed=TRUE)` yet?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That gives this back: `name\rsurname`. Also, reading documentation I think it has to be fixed= FALSE? So it does the replacement using regular expression and not as a literal string.

Comment: Aleg, it does not **NOT** give back `\r` as part of *literal text*. The `\r` is a part of the *string literal*. See my answer. `fixed=FALSE` is only required when you need to use a regex. Not the case here.

Comment: Oh I understand, did not know it worked like that, thanks. I´m curious, is possible for literal text to have returns, new lines, etc. as an element of a vector in R?

Comment: Ok so although it is displayed as text\rtext the return is actually there, thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use

```
gsub(".", "\r", df$col1, fixed=TRUE)
```

The `"\r"` is a string literal defining a carriage return, `"\\r"` is a combination of `\` and `r`.

Since you need to replace a literal character with another literal character you do not need a regex, hence the `fixed=TRUE` argument.

See the [R demo online](https://ideone.com/rT8I4N):

```
col1 = c( "name.surname", "name.surname", "name.surname")
df <- as.data.frame( col1 )
gsub(".", "\r", df$col1, fixed=TRUE)
cat(gsub(".", "\r", df$col1, fixed=TRUE), collapse="\n")
```

Output:

```
[1] "name\rsurname" "name\rsurname" "name\rsurname"
name
surname name
surname name
surname
```

I inlcuded `cat(...)` on purpose, just to show the *literal text* output after `gsub` operation, since many believe the real text contains some escape sequences and not literal chars. Also, see [Remove backslashes from character string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28204507) to avoid this misunderstanding.

Comment: Is not posible in R to define the return inside the string? Similar to what I show in the `# desire output`

Comment: @AleG These are just *display* issues, the CR char ***is*** inside each string.