# R: How to replace space (' ') in string with a *single* backslash and space ('\ ')

Tags: regex, r, replace

I've searched many times, and haven't found the answer here or elsewhere. I want to replace each space `' '` in variables containing file names with a `'\ '`. (A use case could be for shell commands, with the spaces escaped, so each file name doesn't appear as a list of arguments.) I have looked through the StackOverflow question ["how to replace single backslash in R"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27491986/r-gsub-replacing-backslashes), and find that many combinations do work as advertised:

```
> gsub(" ", "\\\\", "a b")
[1] "a\\b"

> gsub(" ", "\\ ", "a b", fixed = TRUE)
[1] "a\\ b"
```

but try these with a single-slash version, and R ignores it:

```
> gsub(" ", "\\ ", "a b")
[1] "a b"

> gsub(" ", "\ ", "a b", fixed = TRUE)
[1] "a b"
```

For the case going in the opposite direction — removing slashes from a string, it works for two:

```
> gsub("\\\\", " ", "a\\b")
[1] "a b"

> gsub("\\", " ", "a\\b", fixed = TRUE)
[1] "a b"
```

However, for single slashes some inner perversity in R prevents me from even attempting to remove them:

```
> gsub("\\", " ", "a\\b")
Error in gsub("\\", " ", "a\\b") : 
  invalid regular expression '\', reason 'Trailing backslash'

> gsub("\", " ", "a\b", fixed = TRUE)
Error: unexpected string constant in "gsub("\", " ", ""
```

The 'invalid regular expression' is telling us something, but I don't see what. (Note too that the `perl = True` option does not help.)

Even with three back slashes R fails to notice even one:

```
> gsub(" ", "\\\ ", "a b")
[1] "a b"
```

The patter extends too! Even multiples of two work:

```
> gsub(" ", "\\\\\\\\", "a b")
[1] "a\\\\b"
```

but not odd multiples (should get `'\\\ '`:

```
> gsub(" ", "\\\\\\ ", "a b")
[1] "a\\ b"

> gsub(" ", "\\\ ", "a b", fixed = TRUE)
[1] "a\\ b"
```

(I would expect 3 slashes, not two.)

My two questions are:

- How can my goal of replacing a `' '` with a `'\ '` be accomplished?
- Why did the odd number-slash variants of the replacements fail, while the even number-slash replacements worked?

For shell commands a simple work-around is to quote the file names, but part of my interest is just wanting to understand what is going on with R's regex engine.

Comment: Try `cat()` ing some of your results - `\b` is a backspace character, like `\n` is a line-break and `\t` is a tab character. E.g. - `cat("remove_one_letter_from_the_end\b")` - Two slashes "\\" is actually a single slash - the R console just adds an extra one to escape it. `cat("\\", sep="\n")`

Comment: @thelatemail You posted your comment when I was halfway writing an answer.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - all good - I think you've covered the main issues!

Comment: A good suggestion @thelatemail. Clearly some, if not all of the explanation is in what `print()` is doing. However, if I try `cat(gsub(" ", "\\ ", "a z"))`, the result is `"a z"` with the newline removed — but notice that the z is not escaped, and the space between the letters remains ...

Comment: @user3897315 - it gets more complex inside `gsub` - because a slash can be used to specify things like `\s` for a space in regex, it needs to have extra escaping, so R needs `\\s` to represent a space. Which means you actually need four slashes "\\\\" to represent a slash because otherwise it will mean nothing - `cat(gsub(" ", "\\\\ ", "a z"))`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Get ready for a face-palm, because this:

```
> gsub(" ", "\\\ ", "a b", fixed = TRUE)
[1] "a\\ b"
```

is actually working.

The two backslashes you see are just the R console's way of displaying a single backslash, which is escaped when printed to the screen.

To confirm the replacement with a single backslash is indeed working, try writing the output to a text file and inspect yourself:

```
f <- file("C:\\output.txt")
writeLines(gsub(" ", "\\", "a b", fixed = TRUE), f)
close(f)
```

In `output.txt` you should see the following:

```
a\b
```

Comment: I don't think you need the third slash - `gsub(" ", "\\ ", "a b", fixed = TRUE)` should be sufficient

Comment: Thank you. Yes to the face-palm; it makes sense, now that I see R's print statement is including those 'helpful' escaping backslashes. I don't yet see why it is helpful to have the extra backslash  in the output of the print — neither Perl nor python include it in their displayed prints — but with that known, I am able to proceed.

Comment: @user51462 `fixed = TRUE` tells R to not use a regex engine when replacing.  Instead, it will use the literal expression you pass it.

Comment: Um...it _does_ only apply to the first argument.

Answer (score 3):

Very helpful discussion! (I've been Googling the heck out of this for 2 days.)

Another way to see the difference (rather than writing to a file) is to compare the contents of the string using `print` and `cat`.

```
z <- gsub(" ", "\\", "a b", fixed = TRUE)

> print(z)
[1] "a\\ b"

> cat(z)
a\ b
```

So, by using `cat` instead of `print` we can confirm that the `gsub` line is doing what was intended when we're trying to add single backslashes to a string.

Comment: And maybe/ideally future versions of `base::shQuote` could simplify/automate this process for all of us?