# Replacing white space with one single backslash

Tags: r, regex, replace, character

I want to replace a white space with ONE backslash and a whitespace like this:

```
"foo bar" --> "foo\ bar"
```

I found how to replace with [multiple backslashes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27491986/3250126) but wasn't able to adapt it to a single backslash.

I tried this so far:

```
x <- "foo bar" 
gsub(" ", "\\ ", x)
# [1] "foo bar"

gsub(" ", "\\\ ", x)
# [1] "foo bar"

gsub(" ", "\\\\ ", x)
# [1] "foo\\ bar"
```

However, all the outcomes do not satisfy my needs. I need the replacement to dynamically create file paths which contain folders with names like

`/some/path/foo bar/foobar.txt`.

To use them for shell commands in `system()` white spaces have to be exited with a `\` to

`/some/path/foo\ bar/foobar.txt`.

Do you know how to solve this one?

Comment: forward slashes are better for this

Comment: I edited my question to demonstrate the use.

Comment: you *might* be able to surround the path containing spaces with quotation marks to get it to work in `system()` ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is a confusion between the *content* of a string and its *representation*. When you print out a string in the ordinary way in R you will *never* see a single backslash (unless it's denoting a special character, e.g. `print("y\n")`.  If you use `cat()` instead, you'll see only a single backslash.

```
x <- "foo bar"
y <- gsub(" ", "\\\\ ", x)
print(y)
## [1] "foo\\ bar"
cat(y,"\n")  ## string followed by a newline
## foo\ bar
```

There are 8 characters in the string; 6 letters, one space, and the backslash.

```
nchar(y)  ## 8
```

For comparison, consider `\n` (newline character).

```
z <- gsub(" ", "\n ", x)
print(z)
## [1] "foo\n bar"
cat(z,"\n")
## foo
##  bar 
nchar(z)  ## 8
```

If you're constructing file paths, it might be easier to use forward slashes instead - forward slashes work as file separators in R on all operating systems (even Windows). Or check out `file.path()`. (Without knowing exactly what you're trying to do, I can't say more.)

Answer (score 4):

To replace a space with one backslash and a space, you do not even need to use regular expression, use your `gsub(" ", "\\ ", x)` first attempt with `fixed=TRUE`:

```
> x <- "foo bar" 
> res <- gsub(" ", "\\ ", x, fixed=TRUE)
> cat(res, "\n")
foo\ bar
```

See an [online R demo](https://ideone.com/Fc7EnY)

The `cat` function displays the "real", literal backslashes.