# Replace plus minus sign with equivalent LaTeX command

Tags: r, regex, unicode, latex

Like the title says, I am trying to replace plus-minus signs with the equivalent LaTeX command "\pm" using `R`

I have tried the following with no success:

```
gsub("±", "\\pm", "±", fixed = FALSE)
```

> "pm"

```
gsub("\u00b1", "\\pm", "\u00b1", fixed = FALSE)
```

> "pm"

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You needed to do it once more. You need four backslash to represent one ([Read more here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27492072/7128934)).

```
gsub("±", "\\\\pm", "±")
#[1] "\\pm"
```

It is actually only one backslash. Check by running:

```
cat(gsub("±", "\\\\pm", "±"))
#\pm
```

Comment: If you used `fixed = TRUE`, you can skip escaping them for regex purposes: `sub("±", "\\pm", "±", fixed = TRUE)`