# time pattern in list.files function (R)

Tags: r, regex

I'm trying to get a list of subdirectories from a path. These subdirectories have a time pattern month\day\hour, i.e. `03\21\11`. 
I naively used the following:

```
 list.files("path",pattern="[0-9]\[0-9]\[0-9]", recursive = TRUE, include.dirs = TRUE)
```

But it doesn't work.
How to code for the digitdigit\digitdigit\digitdigit pattern here?
Thank you

Comment: Maybe you pattern should be something like `[0-9]{2}\[0-9]{2}\[0-9]{2}`. This works?

Comment: `[0-9]` matches only one number. You need to use a quantifier (`+` or `{2}`) after each. Also, you need to escape the backslashes with another backslash `\\`

Comment: You might be able to get away with `"[\\d\\]+"` for just a string of digits and backslashes, if there are not likely to be any in a different configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Regex works for `10\11\18`.

```
(\d\d\\\d\d\\\d\d)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you may need lazy matching for regex, unless there's always two digits - in which case other responses look valid.

If you could provide a vector of file name strings, that would be super helpful.

Capturing backslashes is confusing, I've found this thread helpful: [R - gsub replacing backslashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27491986/r-gsub-replacing-backslashes)

My guess is something like this: `'[0-9]+?\\\\[0-9]+?\\\\[0-9]+'`