# Replacing Backward slash in R

Tags: r, stringr

I want to replace `backward slashes` with `forwards slashes` in a string. So I used below syntax in R.

```
stringr::str_replace("\\", "//", "\\asd")
```

However it fails to replace the `backward slashes` in the given string.

Could you please help to find the right way to replace them?

I am using R in Windows 10 machine

Comment: You might want to check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/27491986/9022665

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the arguments in the wrong order and you need to escape the backslashes.

```
> stringr::str_replace("\\asd", "\\\\", "//")
[1] "//asd"
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
str_replace("\\asd", fixed("\\"), "//")
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `gsub` function in R which is used for replacement operations. The functions takes the input and substitutes it against the specified value.

```
gsub("\\\\", "/", x)
```