# Second evaluation of inline R code in knitr

Tags: r, knitr

I'm trying to create a math test generator which randomizes which questions that are included in a test. I imagine writing 20 questions or so in knitr, and then pressing a button to create a pdf with a subset of them. I'm using R Markdown in Rstudio. I imagine a solution somewhat like:

````
```{r}
start<-"";end<-""

if(0<runif(1)){
start1<-"```{r, echo=F}" 
end1<-"```"
}
```

`r start1`
Question 1
`r end1`
````

But this results in a pdf with:

````
```{r, echo=F}
Question 1
```
````

How do I tell knitr to evaluate the inline code a second time? Or is there a slicker way of doing things?

Comment: personally, I'd use the following strategy: i) in a first invisible chunk, write the code for your chunks to an external R file; ii) use the code externalisation feature to evaluate those in subsequent chunks. You could probably use `knit_expand()`, but I prefer having the intermediate file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `cat` for that:

````
---
title: "Math test"
---

```{r Setup-Chunk, echo=FALSE}
q1 <- "Note down the Pythagorean theorem?"
q2 <- "Sum of angles of a triangle?"
q3 <- "What is the root of $x^2$?"
questions <- c(q1,q2,q3)
selection <- sample(length(questions), 2) # by altering 2 you pick the number of questions
```

```{r, results='asis', echo=FALSE}
out <- c()
for(i in selection){
  out <- c(out, questions[i])
}
cat(paste("###", seq_along(selection), out,collapse = "  \n"))
```
````

Visual:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your ideas, I was unaware of the externalisation part of knitR. However, I don't get cat to accept anything like "$\lambda$" and that won't do. 

Reading from external R-scripts using read_chunk makes my text look like R-code as far as I can understand, I would like normal text... any thoughts on that?

Comment: You need to write `$\\lambda$` as "\" is a special character.
See this post as reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11806501/backslash-in-r-string