# How to replace a symbol by a backslash in R?

Tags: regex, r

Could you help me to replace a char by a backslash in R? My trial:

```
gsub("D","\\","1D2")
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: @DavidArenburg Correct, the string is used later in Sweave/LaTex as a path

Comment: For paths you shouldn’t use backslashes. All modern operating systems support the forward slash as path separator, and using a backslash is **never** the correct option because it does *not* work on most operating systems (essentially it only works on Windows). If you don’t want to use the forward slash (for whatever reason), use the value of `.Platform$file.sep` instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to re-escape the backslash because it needs to be escaped once as part of a normal R string (hence `'\\'` instead of `'\'`), and *in addition* it’s handled differently by `gsub` in a replacement pattern, so it needs to be escaped again. The following works:

```
gsub('D', '\\\\', '1D2')
# "1\\2"
```

The reason the result looks different from the desired output is that R doesn’t actually print the result, it prints an interpretable R string (note the surrounding quotation marks!). But if you use `cat` or `message` it’s printed correctly:

```
cat(gsub('D', '\\\\', '1D2'), '\n')
# 1\2
```

Comment: Thanks for the second part. It was driving me crazy why I could only get it to print multiples of 2 backslashes.

Answer (score 5):

When inputting backslashes from the keyboard, always escape them:

```
gsub("D","\\\\","1D2")
#[1] "1\\2"
```

or,

```
gsub("D","\\","1D2", fixed=TRUE)
#[1] "1\\2"
```

or,

```
library(stringr)
str_replace("1D2","D","\\\\")
#[1] "1\\2"
```

**Note:** If you want something like `"1\2"` as output, I'm afraid you can't do that in R (at least in my knowledge). You can use forward slashes in path names to avoid this.

For more information, refer to this issue raised in R help: [How to replace double backslash with single backslash in R](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/replace-double-backslash-with-singel-backslash-td3989434.html).

Comment: Isn't the Result of this "1\\2". But how to get __a backslash__ meaning one backslash only aka "1\2"

Comment: @Floo0 May be this link helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11806501/backslash-in-r-string

Comment: @Floo0 if you see `1\\2` printed on screen, that represents one backslash, not two.

Answer (score 0):

```
gsub("\\p{S}", "\\\\", text, perl=TRUE);
```

\p{S} ... Match a character from the Unicode category symbol.

Comment: That doesn't give the desired output

Comment: The task was to replace a symbol, not a character.