# How to replace $ with \$ in R?

Tags: r

I want to convert `$ankit` to `\$ankit` in R. I have tried the following, which does not work:

```
gsub("$","\$","$ankit", fixed=TRUE)
# Error: '\$' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting ""\$"
gsub("$","\\$","$ankit", fixed=TRUE)
# [1] "\\$ankit"
gsub("$","\\U0024","$ankit", fixed=TRUE)
# [1] "\\U0024ankit"
gsub("$","\U0024","$ankit", fixed=TRUE)
# [1] "$ankit"
```

Comment: You have to do `\\$` `cat(gsub("$","\\$","$ankit", fixed=TRUE), '\n')`  also check `nchar('\\$')`

Comment: Are you saying that \\$ works, and its just that while displaying the answer R is showing the additional \ in "\\$ankit" just to write it in an escaped manner.

Comment: You can check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11806501/backslash-in-r-string)

Comment: Thanks \\$ indeed works. I was getting confused due to the fact that the output when displayed on R console itself had escape sequence.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have to double escape characters in R because the first `\` escapes the second `\`, and the second one escapes the desired character.

You also have to double square brackets when using regular expressions for the same reason. `[[:alnum:]]`

See R's [regex instructions](http://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/functions/regex)  and the examples in [grep](http://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/functions/grep)
.
`\\$` will do what you want as @akrun suggests in his comment.