# Searching a backslash in a string received from external source

Tags: r, string, backslash

I have a string I received from my DB, so in R it looks like:

```
a <- c("www", "x", "yes", "\303\243")

> a
[1] "www" "x"   "yes" "Ã£"
```

What I want to do is to find which of the elements has backslash in it.
I tried:

```
grepl('\\',a[4])
```

But I keep getting the error

> invalid regular expression '\', reason 'Trailing backslash'

no matter whether I use `cat` or `fixed=T`.

How do I find that backslash in the list?

Comment: Have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11806501/backslash-in-r-string ?

Comment: `a[4]` => `[1] "Ã£"` : R directly interprets \303 and \243 as the corresponding symbols

Comment: Maybe `Encoding(a) == "latin1"` ?

Comment: interesting, you arent allowed to search for that character.  `as.integer(charToRaw("\\")); grepl("\092", a, useBytes=TRUE, fixed=TRUE)` is an error.

Comment: The simple truth is that there is no backslash in any element of `a`. Consider this string: `"Hello World!\n"`. Do you think there is a backslash in it? Furthermore, if you want to find backslash in a string with `grep`, you should: `grepl("\\\\",a[4])`, which is `FALSE` of course.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the backslash twice, once for the String literal in R and once for the regular Expression. `grepl("\\", a[4])` applies the regexp `\`, while `grepl("\\\\", a[4])` applies the regexp `\\`. To view the escaped string literal you can use `cat("\\")`.

But i think your string does not contain any backslash at all, because in the definition the backslash occurs in an escape sequence, not as a character itself.