# How to Include \* in String in R?

Tags: r, regex

How can I include the escape character `\` in a string, followed by `*`?

My incorrect string assignment:
`commandLine.rmTags = 'tag --remove \* test_file.png'`

results in:
`Error: '\*' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting "'tag --remove \*"`

Ultimately, the reason I need to do this is to call `system()` from R, for which the argument is the string above. I will be using it like this:

```
commandLine.rmTags = 'tag --remove \* test_file.png'
system(commandLine.rmTags)
```

Note: if you are curious, I am using [jdberry's very cool Tag Terminal application](https://github.com/jdberry/tag).

Comment: You need to escape the slash with another slash. So use `"\\*"`

Comment: This link might help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11806501/how-to-escape-backslashes-in-r-string

Comment: Thank you very much, both comments were helpful! I did not know that even though the string appeared as having two backslashes then, when I use `cat()` it shows the one backslash.