# Remove specific characters from values in dataframe in R

Tags: r, regex, dataframe, rstudio, gsub

I am new to R and I have a dataframe that has a character class column with the following format:

```
> head(unique(season_advanced_stats$Player))
[1] "alex abrines\\abrinal01"  "quincy acy\\acyqu01"      "steven adams\\adamsst01" 
[4] "arron afflalo\\afflaar01" "alexis ajinca\\ajincal01" "cole aldrich\\aldrico01"
```

I was trying to use gsub but Rstudio kept outputing the "+" symbol everytime I entered the following code indicating that I haven't finished something:

```
season_advanced_stats$Player = gsub('\', '', season_advanced_stats$Player)
```

If anyone can help me figure out how to properly use gsub so only players names are remaining I'd appreciate it!

Comment: You want to remove also numbers? If not, try `gsub("\\\\", "",season_advanced_stats$Player)`

Comment: I want to remove "\\" and the abbreviated name with numbers in them that comes after the backslashes.

Comment: Then try this: `gsub("\\\\|\\d", "",season_advanced_stats$Player)`

Comment: This is close but it still outputs the characters after the backslashes.  How do you recommend I remove everything after the backslashes as well so only the players names before the backslashes remain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can remove everything after backslash with using

```
 gsub("\\\\.*", "", data/vector)
```

So my example

```
v <- c("alex abrines\\abrinal01" , "quincy acy\\acyqu01") 

gsub("\\\\.*", "", v)
```

And output

```
[1] "alex abrines" "quincy acy"
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the `/`. Currently, R thinks `'\', '`, after `gsub`, is a single string, because the `/` is actually escaping the first `'`, making R ignore it as far as ending that first string goes. It's giving you a `+` as a prompt for the final `'`, which it believes it is still waiting for.

```
season_advanced_stats$Player = gsub('\\', '', season_advanced_stats$Player)
```

Should work.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11806501/how-to-escape-backslashes-in-r-string).