# Remove a single backslash in paste0 output

Tags: r

```
paste0(" SqlCmd -s sqlserver2 -Q ", "\"BACKUP DATABASE [mydb] TO DISK = '","D:/temp/mydbcopy.bak' ")
```

is giving output as

```
" SqlCmd -s sqlserver2 -Q \"BACKUP DATABASE [mydb] TO DISK = 'D:/temp/mydbcopy.bak' "
```

but I want the output to be without the backslash

```
" SqlCmd -s sqlserver2 -Q "BACKUP DATABASE [mydb] TO DISK = 'D:/temp/mydbcopy.bak' " "
```

Please help.

Comment: A single backslash is a escape character in CRAN. Try replacing it with double backslash? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11806501/how-to-escape-backslashes-in-r-string

Comment: Thanks, Adam. I tried but it shows the syntax error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code does the correct thing.

The backslash isn’t actually in the string, just as the surrounding quotes aren’t in the string. That’s just how R displays character strings in the terminal. To see the *actual* string content, use `message`:

```
x = paste0(" SqlCmd -s sqlserver2 -Q ", "\"BACKUP DATABASE [mydb] TO DISK = '","D:/temp/mydbcopy.bak' ") 
message(x)
```

This also shows you that your string is (probably) currently missing a closing `"` character.

As a general rule I strongly recommend *against* building command lines using raw string functions, it’s error-prone and hard to read. Use `shQuote` instead: this function is purpose-built to ensure correctly quoted arguments.

```
cmd_tokens = c("SqlCmd", "-s", "sqlserver2", "-Q", "BACKUP DATABASE [mydb] TO DISK = 'D:/temp/mydbcopy.bak'")
cmd = paste(shQuote(cmd_tokens), collapse = " ")
```

Here, each token of the command line (the command itself and all the arguments) are individual strings in a vector, and we apply `shQuote` to all of them in turn before concatenating them. Better yet, instead of concatenating the command yourself, pass the tokens *as they are* to the `system2` command to execute it:

```
args = c("-s", "sqlserver2", "-Q", "BACKUP DATABASE [mydb] TO DISK = 'D:/temp/mydbcopy.bak'")

system2("SqlCmd", args)
```

Comment: Thanks, Konrad. I wasted so much time thinking why the backslash is getting shown, but you're right when I do print the output of paste0 I get correct results. I fixed the ending " issue. Thanks a lot for helping and providing info about shQuote, I'll try to follow your advice.