# I want to extract the first string before "\" to create a new variable in a data.frame

Tags: r

System: Windows 10, R 3.6.2

I import the data from an EXCEL file into a data.frame. One variable has values like this:

[image: sample data]

What I want is to extract the data before the first `"\"`, and create a new variable.
I tried `split`, `str.split`, `str_extract`, and `gsub`, and none of them works. I think the main problem is the separative sign, but I still don't know how to work around. I really appreciate if anyone can help me with this.

Comment: Try `sub("\\\\.*", "", df$account)`

Comment: Another option is `sub("[\\].*", "", df$account)`.

Comment: thank you guys very much, it do works. But why there's 4 "\"? As I checked, I should add 2 "\\"before "\" to stand for "\".

Comment: You must have 2 `"\\"`. So one of them becomes `"\\"` and the other also becomes `"\\"`.

Comment: Why 4? You do need to escape the backspace. try doing `nchar('\\')` and see how many characters you have. Now you need to escape it so that it is literal. ie you need 2 backslashes as you said. Can you think of a way to make `nchar('\\')` give you 2 instead of 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `sub` and remove everything after first backslash.

```
sub("\\\\.*", "", df$account)
```

Another option is to capture everything before first backslash.

```
sub("(.*?)\\\\.*", "\\1", df$account)
```

Regarding why you need 4 `"\"`, read [How to escape backslashes in R string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11806501/how-to-escape-backslashes-in-r-string) .

Comment: thank you very much. But what I mean is that, as I checked, "\\" stand for "\", so what I inputed is "\\\*", where "\\" stand for "\", and "*" to include everything behind "\". But it doesn't work. Why there has to be "\\."? would you please help me?

Comment: @Ryan To include everything behind "\" you need to use `.*` and not only `*`.

Comment: Thank you very much, you do help me a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to extract the first four characters in the string, which come before the "\" sign. One solution is to load the `stringr` library, and extract the substring.

```
library(stringr)
str_sub(string, 1, 4)
```

Hope it helps!